# Is AI21SemanticTextSplitter (from langchain_ai21) Deprecated?

Tags: langchain, chunking

Has anyone tried using Langchain's AI21 integration AI21SemanticTextSplitter?

There is a mention of it on [Langchain's Text Splitters Page](https://stackoverflow.com).

This is [its documentation](https://stackoverflow.com).

I tried the examples given there and it says `ImportError: cannot import name 'AI21SemanticTextSplitter' from 'langchain_ai21' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_ai21/__init__.py)` .

I have installed the required package (`pip install langchain-ai21`). It was suggested to install llama index and update langchain, which I have done.

I was wondering if it has been deprecated or is it just an updation in the package?
Any help would be appreciated.